# How to define static properties for UploadFormat in Restler?

Tags: php, restler

Where and how should I define allowedMimeTypes and other properties for UploadFormat with Restler

---

This is related to [Handling file uploads with Restler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487201/handling-file-uploads-with-restler) and item 2 in the answer section

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UploadFormat is special as it throws exceptions at the `get` stage before we do routing to find the correct api method to call, so settings can only be done in index.php level

If the `allowedMimeTypes` are same across all api classes this is straight forward otherwise you need to do something like

```
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'document')) {
    UploadFormat::$allowedMimeTypes = array('application/pdf'); //,'image/jpeg'
}
```

In the example makes PDF as the only option when the called url contains the string "document"

We have also added a new feature today which enables handling the exception thrown at the api method level

```
UploadFormat::$suppressExceptionsAsError = true;
```

will pass the exception along with the file info

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I first tried putting: 
`@class UploadFormat {@allowedMimeTypes application/pdf, application/csv}` 
before the method called but it didn't work for some reason.

This in index.php however worked:
`use Luracast\Restler\Format\UploadFormat;

UploadFormat::$allowedMimeTypes = array("application/pdf","application/csv");`

But this way I cannot set it method by method. Also this can't be set in the class constructor since it never gets there.

Comment: You are right! since UploadFormat is used at the `get` stage we can not set its properties using api class level. I'm updating my answer to reflect this